# Is there a faster way to blit many images on Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a "map" / track:

```
track_data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

Each of these numbers represent an image. As you'll see on the class, I blit each one of them at each loop. If I blit them only once and don't fill the background to increase performance, the moving objects (The cars) paint the screen in a brush-like fashion (Obviously). So, I have to draw them at each frame. The thing is: It's too damn slow. Is there a faster way to blit them?

```
class Track:

    TRACK_SIZE = 16

    START = 0
    DIRT = 1
    ROAD = 2

    DIRT_IMAGE = "gfx/dirt.png"
    ROAD_IMAGE = "gfx/road.png"

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = test.track_data
        self.spawnpoints = test.track_spawnpoints
        self.waypoints = test.track_waypoints
        self.actors = []
        self.spawn_positions = {}
        self.actor_dimensions = [
            options["RESOLUTION"][0] / 16,
            options["RESOLUTION"][1] / 16
        ]
        self.updated = False
        for row in self.data:
            actor_row = []
            for column in row:
                if column == Track.START:
                    pass
                elif column == Track.DIRT:
                    actor_row.append(pygame.image.load(Track.DIRT_IMAGE))
                elif column == Track.ROAD:
                    actor_row.append(pygame.image.load(Track.ROAD_IMAGE))
            self.actors.append(actor_row)
        occurence_counter = 0
        for y in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
            for x in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
                if self.spawnpoints[y][x] != 0:
                    self.spawn_positions[occurence_counter] = (
                        x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]) + Car.WIDTH,
                        y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1]) + Car.HEIGHT
                    )
                    occurence_counter += 1

    def draw(self, surface):
        if not self.updated:
            for y in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
                for x in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
                    surface.blit(
                        self.actors[y][x], 
                        [x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]), y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1])]
                    ) # Here <<<
```

Comment: There is no blit faster than no blit. You should take a look at the dirty rect animation concept. http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html (around the first third of the page).
It can really speed up by tens your code ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Can't believe I've skipped a material called "newbieguide" hahaha, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but a huge performance boost would also be:

```
DIRT_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("gfx/dirt.png").convert() # if you dont have transparency
ROAD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("gfx/road.png").convert_alpha # if you have transparency


actor_row.append(DIRT_IMAGE)
actor_row.append(ROAD_IMAGE )
```

1) You don't have to load the image so often, but only load it once (which helps for loading times in the beginning)

2) Using ".convert()" on your images gives you a huge performance boost throughout your 'gamecycle' or however often you blit them - especially if you blit many images over a broad area

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was quite easy to solve the problem. All I had to do was to create an intermediary surface of the size of the screen, of the size of the track, and blit all the ground images to it just once, and then on the main loop blit the intermediary track surface instead of the 256 individual images.

```
class Track:

    TRACK_SIZE = 16

    DIRT = 1
    ROAD = 2

    DIRT_IMAGE = "gfx/dirt.png"
    ROAD_IMAGE = "gfx/road.png"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ground_data = test.track_ground_data
        self.spawnpoints = test.track_spawnpoints
        self.waypoints = test.track_waypoints
        self.actors = []
        self.ground_positions = {}
        self.spawn_positions = {}
        self.waypoint_positions = {}
        self.actor_dimensions = [
            options["RESOLUTION"][0] / 16,
            options["RESOLUTION"][1] / 16
        ]
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((options["RESOLUTION"][0], options["RESOLUTION"][1]), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        for row in self.ground_data:
            actor_row = []
            for column in row:
                if column == Track.DIRT:
                    actor_row.append(pygame.image.load(Track.DIRT_IMAGE))
                elif column == Track.ROAD:
                    actor_row.append(pygame.image.load(Track.ROAD_IMAGE))
            self.actors.append(actor_row)
        for y in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
            for x in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
                if self.ground_data[y][x] != 0:
                    self.ground_positions[(
                        x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]),
                        y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1])
                    )] = self.ground_data[y][x]
                if self.spawnpoints[y][x] != 0:
                    self.spawn_positions[self.spawnpoints[y][x]] = (
                        x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]) + Car.WIDTH,
                        y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1]) + Car.HEIGHT
                    )
                if self.waypoints[y][x] != 0:
                    self.waypoint_positions[self.waypoints[y][x]] = (
                        x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]) + Car.WIDTH,
                        y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1]) + Car.HEIGHT
                    )
        # Blitting the track images to the track surface for greater performance.
        for y in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
            for x in range(Track.TRACK_SIZE):
                self.surface.blit(
                    self.actors[y][x], 
                    [x*int(self.actor_dimensions[0]), y*int(self.actor_dimensions[1])]
                )

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.surface, (0, 0))
```